# Using the switch variable with Matrix

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to use the switch variable with Matrix with no success - nothing is output. This is on the latest Matrix and EE 2.5.5:

```
{panels}

    <div class="panel {switch=panel-n1|panel-n2|panel-n3|panel-n4}">

        <h2>{headline}</h2>

        <div class="editor-content">
            panel_text here
        </div>

        {if structure_page OR url}
            <a href="{if structure_page}{structure_page}{if:else}{url}{/if}" class="cta" title="{headline}">{cta}</a>   
        {/if}

    </div>

{/panels}
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Argh, sorry. Was missing quotes:

```
{switch='panel-n1|panel-n2|panel-n3|panel-n4'}
```

Doh!

Comment: Please feel free to accept your own answer, so the issue is marked as resolved or not open.